# How to be called cellForItemAt of collectionView under scrollView

Tags: swift, storyboard, swift5

My Storyboard has ScrollView and CollectionView. Hierarchy is like this

```
ScrollView
  View
    Button
    TextField
    CollectionView
    Button
```

In this case, cellForItemAt of CollectionView is not called. But when I put CollectionView out of ScrollView, cellForItemAt is called.

How can I call cellForItemAt when CollectionView is under ScrollView?

Comment: Can you provide the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Check height of your CollectionView inside ScrollView. Height must be over 0 to call `cellForItemAt` in CollectionView.

Comment: You are right. I added height and it works. I designed collectionView with top, bottom, left and right. Thanks.